# Conditional alarm clock

Tags: android, gps, reminders

I am a heavy sleeper who needs a "smart" mobile alarm.
In terms of being smart, I want it to **ring only if I (the device) am or am not at a specific area(s) at the specified time**.

For example, I have to leave home at least by 9:15 for work to get on time. I can then set an alarm like:

```
time     : 09:17 AM on weekdays
location : home
condition: when I AM there
ringtone : the_most_noisy_annoying_music_cause_i_m_still_home.mp3
```

or in a more challenging way:

```
time     : 09:18 AM on weekdays
location : (the "path" from my place to work which I've previously set)
condition: when I am NOT there
ringtone : i_am_screwed.mp3
```

---

### Requirements:

- to be an Android app
- *(optional)* to keep silent if it's unsure with where itself is

Comment: Would you accept an app that can do that *amongst other things*, and is not free (i.e. you have to pay a little)? As you didn't specify a price criterium: any budget (limit)?

Comment: @Izzy Sure I would. I feel like i can pay up to 10 USDs. What is that called?

Comment: As the budget fits: See below, and enjoy! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>As an app able to do that *amongs other things* is acceptable:</sup>

There are several [Automation tools](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation) available on Android which can be used to achieve this. I'm using **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** for this kind of stuff – and with this app, would approach your goal like this:<sup>1</sup>

We set up a *profile*, which basically joins a *condition* to a *task*. Let's take your first example:

**Profile "I am Here"**:

- Condition:

  - Time: From: 9:17 (no "to", as we want exactly this point in time)
  - Day: Day of week: Chose the days (Mon to Fri)
  - Location: (Set your location)<sup>2</sup>
- Task: *Media › Music Play*, and chose the `.mp3` file to be played

**Profile "I am not there":**

For "the path" things might become a little more tricky. It would work similar to the above, and best thing I can think of is collecting the CellIDs on your path, and use them as "location" (i.e. "anywhere near those CellIDs"). You can also *invert* a condition (which is what you probably need: you're *not* near to any of those CellIDs).

**Personal experience:**

I use similar solutions with *Tasker* e.g. to turn WiFi on when I'm home (via CellIDs – so no GPS or network needed for that), and off when I'm leaving home. Works wonderfully. As a side-effect, you'll get many more opportunities; to get an idea, be welcome to take a look at my [Collection of Tasker Resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker).

Tasker is available at the playstore for about USD 5 / EUR 3. A free 7-day trial is available for download on their homepage. Alternatively, there are some other automation tools which might be capable of the same (see the link above) – e.g. [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama), which comes for free. But as a *Tasker* user, I'm not familiar with the others, so I cannot really comment on them.

---

<sup>**1:** this is just "pseudo-code", not a tested solution – but shows perfectly how to do it with *Tasker*</sup>

<sup>**2:** Tasker can deal with different location sources, e.g. GPS, network location, Cell IDs. Make your choice. In terms of battery usage, GPS is most expensive, CellID least.</sup>

Comment: Oh my goodness, both `Tasker` and `Llama` look so promising! I didn't know that I suck at google-fu. Thank you so much. xD

Comment: Any time, Suzi! And also: when looking for some Android app, don't forget to drive by and check [my Android site](http://android.izzysoft.de/) with its real-life categories for apps – plus the [resource collections](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources) and [articles](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles.php). And when unsure about permissions, check [its permission explanations](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms) as well :)